# How to listen to back key event to android back button using java script in webapp

Tags: javascript

i have created a web base app for android device but back button does not work i want that by pressing back button it navigate to index.html i tried

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', doSomething, false);

  function doSomething(e) {

   windows.load("index.html")  
    e.preventDefault();
   }
```